# Escape from { with TraceSource.TraceEvent

Tags: c#

When I use TraceEvent in TraceSource class :

```
 _warningTSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 0, finalText, new object[0]);
```

I Catch this Exception :`Input string was not in a correct format.`

I realized that '{' character causes this problem. How I can solve it???
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `finalText` and `new object[0]`. It tries to format it according to `finalText` which must be a format in the case when you call the TraceEvent whith 4 parameters:

```
public void TraceEvent(
    TraceEventType eventType,
    int id,
    string format,
    params object[] args
)
```

**From Documentation:**

```
format  Type: System.String
```

*A composite format string (see Remarks) that contains text intermixed with zero or more format items, which correspond to objects in the **args** array.*

```
args Type: System.Object[]
```

*An object array containing zero or more objects to format.*

Your code: `TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 0, finalText, new object[0])`

`finalText` here I suppose is not a format, but is the message you want to display.

You can use the method instead

```
public void TraceEvent(
    TraceEventType eventType,
    int id,
    string message
)
```

Sources: [MSDN (3 params)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5141xyx5(v=vs.110).aspx),  [MSDN (4 params)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdzz33s6(v=vs.110).aspx)